# Using the idiom "peace of mind"

Tags: grammar, idioms

Which usage is more appropriate, or are they equal?

1. It afforded me the luxury of travelling and the peace of mind in knowing that I could work anywhere.
2. It afforded me the luxury of travelling and the peace of mind knowing I could work anywhere.